# Symbol for "covers" in posets

Tags: notation

Has there been any suggestions for a symbol for "cover" relation on posets? (For example on the poset $(\mathbb{Z}, \mid)$ number 12 covers number 6, but does not cover number 3.)

Texts I have seen just says "$a$ covers $b$" or explicitly states "$a \succ b$ and there is no $c$ such that $a \succ c$ and $c \succ b$".

Comment: Why do you want a symbol? Writing things in plain text isn't always a bad thing.

Comment: @najib-idrissi: Of course not. But I think that symbols are somewhat easier to read when phrase would be constantly and often used. Not a big question of course.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to found an example. Enumerative Combinatorics, downloadable from http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/ , on p. 279 uses \lessdot for this.